# Is this a Python Rich's feature or a bug?

Tags: python, debugging, rich, supabase-py

I'm making an app in Python using [Supabase](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/python/introduction) and [Rich](https://github.com/Textualize/rich).
Everytime I make a request to the Supabase API, Rich will print some kind of log, and I don't know if this is a feature that I can disable or a bug.

[image]

I've tried uninstalling Rich and Supabase does not give any output by default.

Also, I've reduced the algorithm to a basic testing file. This is the only thing I do, so it's nothing I could've configured.

```py
from os import environ
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from supabase import Client, create_client

load_dotenv()

URL: str = environ.get('SUPABASE_URL')
KEY: str = environ.get('SUPABASE_KEY')

supa: Client = create_client(URL, KEY)

query = supa.table('watched').select('*').execute()
```

### Solution

Finally I've solved it after trying some methods:

```py
import logging
import sys

supabase_logger = logging.getLogger('supabase')
rich_logger = logging.getLogger('rich')

# Method 1
supabase_logger.propagate = False
rich_logger.propagate = False

# Method 2
supabase_logger.disabled = True
rich_logger.disabled = True

# Method 3 (51 must be any number above 50)
logging.disable(51)

# Method 4 (This is the one that worked for me)
logging.disable(sys.maxsize)
```

Comment: Is this the whole code? It doesn't look like you are importing rich here

Comment: Yes, this is the whole code. I'm not importing it, but it's installed in the interpreter. When I uninstall it the output it's not there.

Comment: I'm really confused about what you're asking here. It's perfectly normal for a server to log requests

Comment: This doesn't sound like a bug.  More likely you just need to change your application's logging configs to meet your need; e.g. not send the access log events to the console.  There should be documentation on how to do this.

Comment: I've finally solved it thanks to the answer by collins cheruiyot and some further research. Solution will be added to the post itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#likely due to the default logging configuration in the Supabase Python library

```
import logging

#Disable logging from the Supabase library
logging.getLogger("supabase").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

Comment: Thank you! I've solved it thanks to your answer and some further research.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to turn off the http requests being logged you can add

```
logging.getLogger("httpx").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

According to this github issue:
https://github.com/supabase-community/supabase-py/issues/532